Unity Cloud Save HttpException: (403) HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Error
I didn’t get an error until yesterday, I didn’t make any changes. When I run my application, Unity runs the following code. This code is shared on its tutorial page:
public async void SavePlayerFile()
{
    byte[] file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(“fileName.txt”);
    await CloudSaveService.Instance.Files.Player.SaveAsync(“fileName”, file);
}

I get the following error on this line:
HttpException: (403) HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Unity.Services.CloudSave.Internal.Http.ResponseHandler.HandleAsyncResponse (Unity.Services.CloudSave.Internal.Http.HttpClientResponse response, System.Collections.Generic. Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] statusCodeToTypeMap) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.services.cloudsave/Runtime/com.unity.services.cloudsave.internal/Runtime/Http/ResponseHandler.cs:138)

Important: I can send data with Unity Cloud Save without getting an error, but I get an error when sending a File.

There is no [tag:unityscript] in this question. Removing tag.
